# Lookup field in Edit in Datasheet mode in sharepoint doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint, field, lookup, datasheet

I've added a lookup field to a document library, and it is possible to choose values as expected in "Edit properties" for a single document. However, when in Edit in Datasheet mode all of the dropdowns for the lookup field are EMPTY!!!! Is this just the way it is, or have I done something wrong?

Has anyone managed to get lookup fields to work in Edit in Datasheet mode?

Comment: I can't help solve your problem, but I can confirm that it does work in datasheet mode. I've got several fields added to a document content type and they all can be set in datasheet mode.

Answer (score 2):

Required lookup fields do not show up in datasheet view. You need to make the lookup field optional.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my fields defined as site columns. After opening and saving column definition in list, datasheet started to work perfectly...